# Get x-axis label into the first colomn of the table - highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to create a table from `highcharts`.

I am getting all the data properly to table.but as first column I need the x axis labels. how to get it. As column head I need the `date` and as column values I need date values.

See [jsfiidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/tLNHM/1/).

Screenshot:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

// user options
var tableTop = 310,
    colWidth = 100,
    tableLeft = 20,
    rowHeight = 20,
    cellPadding = 2.5,
    valueDecimals = 1,
    valueSuffix = '';

// internal variables
var chart = this,
    series = chart.series,
    renderer = chart.renderer,
    cellLeft = tableLeft;

// draw category labels
$.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function(i, name) {

    renderer.text(
        name, 
        cellLeft + cellPadding, 
        tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
    )
    .css({
        fontWeight: 'bold',


    })       
    .add();
});


$.each(series, function(i, serie) {
    cellLeft += colWidth;

    // Apply the cell text
    renderer.text(
            serie.name,
            cellLeft - cellPadding + colWidth, 
            tableTop + rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .attr({
            align: 'right'
        })
        .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color:'red'
        })
        .add();

    $.each(serie.data, function(row, point) {

        // Apply the cell text
        renderer.text(
                Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                tableTop + (row + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
            )
            .attr({
                align: 'right'
            })
            .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color:'blue'
        })
            .add();

        // horizontal lines
        if (row == 0) {
            Highcharts.tableLine( // top
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + cellPadding
            );
            Highcharts.tableLine( // bottom
                renderer,
                tableLeft, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding,
                cellLeft + colWidth, 
                tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
            );
        }
        // horizontal line
        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding
        );

    });

    // vertical lines        
    if (i == 0) { // left table border  
        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            tableLeft, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );
    }

    Highcharts.tableLine(
        renderer,
        cellLeft, 
        tableTop + cellPadding,
        cellLeft, 
        tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
    );

    if (i == series.length - 1) { // right table border    

        Highcharts.tableLine(
            renderer,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + cellPadding,
            cellLeft + colWidth, 
            tableTop + (serie.data.length + 1) * rowHeight + cellPadding
        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the x axis labels using:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b',point.x)
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jxSgM/.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `datetime` xAxis, so you can't use categories in `drawTable` code. Instead use `series[0].xData` which contains all timestamps from points. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tLNHM/2/).

Changed part:

```
// draw category labels
$.each(chart.series[0].xData, function(i, name) {

    renderer.text(
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', name), 
        cellLeft + cellPadding, 
        tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
    )
    .css({
        fontWeight: 'bold',


    })       
    .add();
});
```